# Get multiple value to next activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The app activity would random get 10 question from sqlite database. I want get the questions and answers to next activity to show answer. I think it should return the value on the "NextQ" button. How to set it?

```
public class QuizGram extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "eng.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quiz";
    private static final String QUIZ_ID = "_id";
    private static final String QUIZ_TYPE = "quiz_type";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String A = "a";
    private static final String B = "b";
    private static final String C = "c";
    private static final String ANS = "ans";

    List<Question> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView Questions;
    RadioButton Radio0, Radio1, Radio2;
    Button NextQ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quizdetail);

        DBhelper dbHelper = new DBhelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbHelper.openDataBase();
        quesList = this.getQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        Questions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questions);
        Radio0 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        Radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        Radio2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        NextQ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextQ);
        setQuestionView();
        NextQ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
                if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                }
                if(qid<10){                 
                    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizGram.this, QuizResult.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(bundle); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public List<Question> getQuestions() 
    {
         List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        //db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
         Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                 new String[] {QUIZ_ID, QUIZ_TYPE, QUESTION, A, B, C, ANS},
                 QUIZ_TYPE + "='grammar'" ,
                 null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "10");
         // looping through all rows and adding to list
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setTYPE(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList.add(quest);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         // return quest list
         return quesList;
    }

    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        Questions.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        Radio0.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        Radio1.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        Radio2.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent = new Intent(QuizGram.this, Quiz.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple just define this under you onclick functionality where you intent to next activity

```
String strMessage = yourEdittext.getText().toString());
        String strMessage1 = yourEdittext1.getText().toString());
        String strMessage2 = yourEdittext2.getText().toString());
    // so on you can directly set values
    // you have to just set values in string                      

      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextactivity.class)   
      i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strMessage);
      i.putExtra("new_variable_name1",strMessage1);     
      i.putExtra("new_variable_name2",strMessage2);

      startActivity(i);
```

**Then in your next activity retrieve it via**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String var="";
String var1="";
String var2="";
      if (extras != null)
      {

        String value= extras.getString("new_variable_name");       
        value= var;
        String value1= extras.getString("new_variable_name1");
        value1= var1;  

         String value2= extras.getString("new_variable_name2");
         value2= var;
      }
```

Comment: But the activity have 10 questions, I need get value every I click next question so I need get value 10 time. Maybe create a array to store it?

Comment: just take 10 variables... i don't know if we can transfer array as variable in intent..

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying your method, I think it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

1 .You can do this by passing the Question object through intent.
in sending activity ->

`intent .putExtra("Question", currentQ );`

in receiving activity ->

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Question q= (Question) bundle.getSerializable("Question");
```

Make sure to implement Serializable for the Question class.

2.Other option is passing individual values through intent